# Seating of 5 boys and 5 girls with restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

The question is:

> 5 boys($B_i$) and 5 girls($G_i$) where $1\le i\le5$ are to be seated **alternately** in a circle such that $B_i$ does not sit adjacent to $G_i$. Find the number of arrangements.

I have tried taking smaller cases but couldn't find any pattern which could help me solve this. I am pretty much stuck. I need hints on how to begin or approach this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try counting the cases where all 5 forbidden pairs are paired.  Then 4 of 5, 3 of 5, etc.  use inclusion-exclusion.  Once you have counted all of the incorrect seatings, subtract this from the total number of possible seatings.

Comment: Start smaller.  How many ways are there of assigning the seating if there were only two of each gender?  Three? Four?

Comment: @DougM In the IE step how will we count the number of seatings where only one of the forbidden seatings are paired?

Answer (score 1):

Seat all $5$ -- $b_i$ paired with $g_i$

$\frac{5!2^5}{10}$

Pair 4 of 5

$\frac{6!2^4}{10}-\frac{5!2^5}{10}$

Pair 3 of 5

$\frac{7!2^3}{10}-(\frac{6!2^4}{10}-\frac{5!2^5}{10})$

etc.

None paired...

$\frac{10!}{10} - \frac{9!2}{10} + \frac{8!2^2}{10} - \frac{7!2^3}{10} + \frac{6!2^4}{10}-\frac{5!2^5}{10}$

Updtate.....
I think this is right, but I did this pretty quickly.

All paired
$\frac {5!}{5}$

4 paired
$\frac {6!}{2\cdot 5} - \frac {5!}{5}$

3 paired
$\frac {7!}{2^2\cdot 5} - (\text {4-paired})$

$\vdots$

None paired

$\frac {10!}{2^5\cdot 5} - \frac {9!}{2^4\cdot 5}+ \frac {8!}{2^3\cdot 5} - \frac {7!}{2^2\cdot 5} + \frac {6!}{2\cdot 5} - \frac {5!}{5}$

Comment: I am getting the expression for all $5$ paired as $4!2^5$ (as we can permute the $5$ pairs in $4!$ ways in a circle and their individual ordering can be done in $2!$ ways for each) but your expression is $4!2^4$. Which one is correct? Have you considered clockwise and anticlockwise orders as same?

Comment: Obviously, I like my number!  My thought process, arrange the 10 people in a line and  divide by the number of ways to rotate the the table.

Comment: Please check the edit. I had missed an important word "alternate" in the question which changes a lot. I am very sorry for this error.